# How to optimize SQL query/SP using execution plan in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SP which is querying on 12 tables, few are very big tables approximately 15GB of size. I am querying on datetime fields to get one month data with about 15 columns.

Please suggest me step by step approach to write optimize query in **sql server** using indexes.

I can not share execution plan but I can tell you now the only issue with hash match(inner join), it is taking most of the time of execution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the query, table structure, Indexes if any and execution plan of your current query

Comment: like @Prdp said, post more info. You can share the execution plan with: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I am sorry I can not share the plan since its confidential data of a banking client, but I can assure that there is no index scan in my execution plan but maximum time is taken by RID (Heap) lookup.

Comment: Are you intentionally using heaps? They can cause big issues if you aren't handling them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "table scan" and "clustered index scan" both indicate the need for an index on that table or a tweak to an existing index. I'd give you more but this is a massive subject.

If you have an expensive KEY lookup on a clustered index then this can usually be fixed with an appropriate Covering Index.

Comment: RID lookup means that the table does not have a clustered index at all.